# How to get data from exception in lua?

Tags: lua

how to get data as table from exception in lua??

```
x * 2

-- stdin:1: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (global 'x')
-- stack traceback:
--         stdin:1: in main chunk
--         [C]: in ?
```

how to get info from exception?
here example

```
print(getErrorInfo()['message'])
print(getErrorInfo()['line'])

-- attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (global 'x')
-- 1
```

Comment: `x * 2` will cause a syntax error not the quoted error. you'd need to parse the output of the Lua compiler in your host application to handle syntax errors or errors thrown in the top scope of your code. if an error is trown in a function that is called in your Lua code, then you can catch the error using pcall or xpcall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse error message

```
local function func_to_call() x = x*2 end

local ok, err_obj = pcall(func_to_call)
if not ok then
  local line_no, err_mes = tostring(err_obj):match":(%d+): (.*)"
  local err_info = {message = err_mes, line = tonumber(line_no)}
  print(err_info.line, err_info.message)
end
```